# passing responses between observables in RxJava/RxAndroid

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have this code :

```
getLocationObservable() // ---> async operation that fetches the location. 
//  Once location is found(or failed to find) it sends it to this filter :
.filter(location -> {  // ---> I want to use this location in the the onNext in the end

     after finishing some calculation here, I either return 'true' and continue 
     to the next observable which is a Retrofit server call, or simply 
     return 'false' and quit.
})
.flatMap(location -> getRetrofitServerCallObservable( location )
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(
     new Observer<MyCustomResponse>() {
          @Override
          public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
               _disposable = d;
          }
          @Override
          public void onNext(MyCustomResponse response) {
          // I want to be able to use the `location` object here
          }
          @Override
          public void onError(Throwable e) {

          }
          @Override
          public void onComplete() {

          }
     });
```

I want to be able to use the `location` object from line 3(first observable), in the "onNext" that is trigerred by the second observable. 
I can't manage to work it out.. any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you alter `MyCustomResponse` to include the `location`?

Comment: It's the converted json-to-POJO class object that is returned from the retrofit response(the retrofit observable), so it's not really customizable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`getRetrofitServerCallObservable( location )`

you could map the result to be a Pair (from your favourite library) of the response and the location:

`getRetrofitServerCallObservable( location ).map(response -> Pair.create(location, response))`

Then, in your `onNext`, you'd be receiving `Pair<Location,MyCustomResponse>` instances.

If you don't want to use a `Pair` class, you could use `Object[]`, but if you do, please don't tell me about it :P

Comment: it worked, thank you ))
btw, just for the sake of learning, are there any disadvantages to using `Pair`s ion general? performance-wise

Comment: Well, you're allocating an extra object for every element, but if you pick an efficient implementation (or a JVM language that has such a construct built in like Scala's `Tuple2`) I wouldn't worry about that too much. Another alternative would be to write a single closure across the entire `flatMap` call, keeping the `locations` in scope throughout, but that won't make for pretty code.